# Set controller based on value

Tags: angularjs

I have three item types ('A','B' and 'C'), using different controllers, when an item is selected I need to know what function in what controller to call

For example, lets say an item with type 'A' is selected, and we'd like to edit this item, so we press our 'Edit' button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-controller="" ng-click="edit(item)" > <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </button>
```

But how do I set the correct controller ('AController')?

The only way I can think of is using ng-show and ng-hide, like this:

```
<button ng-show="item.Type == 'A'" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-controller="AController" ng-click="edit(item)" > <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </button>
```

But this will give me three buttons (one for each type) for each crud option (I will be able to create new, edit, view and delete item), that amounts to 12 buttons.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There is a "missusage" here. Why not redirect on an "edition" route, how would be attached to the right controller? Otherwise
    edit(item)
would open a modal / window / anything else with the right controller. The first solution seems to be a little bit easier for me...

Answer (score -1):

If items (A, B and C) are objects. you can define methods on them and call them from the view, which should direct you to the correct controller from which they originated.

ex. 
In Controller:

```
function AController() {

    A = {prop1: val1, prop2: val2, ... editItem: editItem}

    function editItem() { this == A }

}
```

In view:

```
ng-click="item.editItem()"
```

Comment: This was downvoted quickly, I would like to know the reason because I use it in a project and it will be helpful. Best regards

Comment: I'd also like to know why this was downvoted, will try it anyways and see how it works, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, hope it helps. I discovered it lately and use it on objects in the view as a shortcut to controller methods and avoid a lot of index and prop searching. Best of luck